# How do you navigate between two pages back and forth and keep state?

Tags: react-native

I'm using createStackNavigator to create my navigation, I have 2 pages
page A (initial) and page B, I want to be able go back from B to A and then
A to B without losing state but it seems that I can only keep state for one navigation (AKA A->B or B->A) because once I pop the stack I can't go back, is there any way around this?

Comment: You need to use props or a state manager like https://redux.js.org/

Comment: I'm using it, but I wanted to ask if it can happen "natively" since I noticed it's a lot faster when I pop than reload state from redux